# tag in front of an equation

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, tags

In a math display, I want to have the tag of an equation at the beginning of the equation. Something, like:

```
(Tag) ax=b.
```

It is not sufficient to just use a text{} or a mbox{} environment, since I want to quote this equation afterward.

Comment: Most document classes accept the option `leqno`, which prints the equation numbers on the left. In combination with the option `fleqn`, which pushes the equation on the left instead of centering it, this might give the result you are looking for.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.